# Airflow macros not converting to date

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I have below hive operator where i have to add partitions based on date.

```
HiveOperator(task_id='add_partition_{}'.format(state),
             hql='alter table my_db.state_wise_records add partition (event_date="{{ ds }}", state="{state}") location "/user/cloudera/state_wise_records/event_date={{ ds }}/state={state}"'.format(state=state),
             dag=dag)
```

However, This is not converting macros to date rather than that I am getting like below

```
/user/cloudera/state_wise_records/event_date={ds}/state=UP
```

What's amiss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use string with parameters in combination with Jinja templates. You will have to split in various strings and concatenate them. For instance:

```py
hql = 'alter table my_db.state_wise_records add partition (event_date="{{ ds }}",' 
+ 'state="{state}")'.format(state=state) 
+ 'location "/user/cloudera/state_wise_records/event_date={{ ds }}/' 
+ 'state={state}"'.format(state=state)
```